# Input data not showing up for dropdowns

Tags: php, html

Update: I'm trying to implement this code that was written by Periplo but its breaking the page, when I look at logs it says unexpected echo. I cant identify the error but its gotta be syntax, can anyone spot it?

```
new code:

 <select name="campaign_owner" id="campaign_owner">
    <option value="*"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>

    <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" <?php ($campaign_owner == $user['username']) ? echo 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I have a form with several inputs. On submit the db is written to and then that data is displayed as individual records on a list. On that list I can edit each record, when edit is clicked the form is loaded back up with the existing information that was entered. This works fine for inputs, but I have a  dropdown that does not act the same way. I think I need to add a loop into this but I dont get quite how to implement that. Ive included two screenschots the first is the add screen with all blank inputs, the 2nd is a edit screen with inputs filled, notice both dropdowns are not showing data(data for those dropdowns has been entered into the db, they are just not showing up for editing)
[[image: add screen]
[[image: edit screen]]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input-campaign-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="campaign_name" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-campaign-name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campaign_name; ?>" />
                    <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                      <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></label>
                      <select name="campaign_owner" id="campaign_owner" value="<?php echo $campaign_owner; ?>">
                        <option value="*"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                      <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                      </select>
                  </div>
```

Comment: You need to check which user to display in your foreach loop. Add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` accordingly

Comment: _"it says unexpected echo"_ `($campaign_owner == $user['username']) ? echo 'selected' : '';` - that's not how the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) works, each part needs to be a valid _expression_, and `echo` is not an expression. The echo needs to go before the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **$campaign_owner** is a user name, try this:

**UPDATED**

```
<select name="campaign_owner" id="campaign_owner">
    <option value="*"><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>

    <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" <?php ($campaign_owner == $user['username']) ? echo 'selected' : echo ''; ?>><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: hey thanks for that, however its breaking, I looked in the error.log and I get an unexpected echo error on the 2nd option value line.